# How to calculate diagonal of a matrix product in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow, diagonal

I have two matrices `A` and `B` of shape `(M, N)` with very large `M` and small `N`.

I would like to multiply them and then take diagonal of a result:

```
C = tf.matmul(A, B)
D = tf.diag_part(C)
```

Unfortunately, this requires of creating of very big `(M, M)` matrix, which can't fit into memory.

But most of this data I don't need. So, is it possible to calculate this value in one step?

Is there something like [`einsum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum) but without summing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is equivalent to:

```
tf.einsum('ij,ij->i', A, B)
```

or:

```
tf.reduce_sum(A * B, axis=1)
```

---

*Example*:

```
A = tf.constant([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]])
B = tf.constant([[3,4],[1,2],[2,3]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.diag_part(tf.matmul(A, B, transpose_b=True)))) 
# [11  8 18]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.reduce_sum(A * B, axis=1)))
#[11  8 18]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.einsum('ij,ij->i', A, B)))
#[11  8 18]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dot product` of `A` and `B transpose` to obtain the same:

```
tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(A, tf.transpose(B)), axis=1)
```

The code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

A = tf.constant([[1,4, 3], [4, 2, 6]])
B = tf.constant([[5,4,],[8,5], [7, 3]])

E = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(A, tf.transpose(B)), axis=1)

C = tf.matmul(A, B)
D = tf.diag_part(C)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

print(sess.run(D))
print(sess.run(E))

#Output
#[58 44]
#[58 44]
```

Comment: This will give `(N,N)` matrix, while I need `(M,1)`